# When my page loads I want useEffect to make the call to my server and setFormValues. But formValues stays in its initial state. What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first time posting. When I console.log(res.data), the results are:  
case_size: "4" 
category: "Dairy" 
createdAt: "2022-05-27T16:08:43.762Z" 
description: "Amish Cntry, unpstr" 
item_name: "Milk" 
location: "Walk-in" 
unit_measure: "1 gal" 
updatedAt: "2022-05-27T16:08:43.762Z" 
__v: 0 
_id: "6290f78bb9acdf9aefadd77b"

But, console.log(formValues) is:
case_size: "" 
category: ""  
description: ""  
item_name: ""  
location: ""  
unit_measure: ""

EditItem.jsx

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
        location: '',
        category: '',
        item_name: '',
        description: '',
        unit_measure: '',
        case_size: ''
    })
useEffect(() => {
    let isCancelled = false
    const getItem = async () => {
        let url = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local' ? `http://localhost:3001/api/item/${id}` : `https://server-inventory-app.herokuapp.com/api/item/${id}`
        const res = await axios.get(url)
        if (!isCancelled) {
            setFormValues(res.data)
            console.log(res.data)
            console.log(formValues)
        }
    }
    getItem()
    return () => {
        isCancelled = true
    }
}, [id])
```

Comment: I can see the formValues updating this way. Now I'm not understanding why the formValues don't render on my page. I have input tags correlated to each key set to the value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

useState hook is async, and will not be changed immediately.

```
setFormValues(res.data) // not updated
console.log(res.data)
```

if you want yo see state updating, you can use useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("updated state:",formValues)
},[formValues])
```